# invalid datetime format

Tags: sql, db2, informatica-powercenter

I have a question about powercenter message code: RR-4035. I have a mapping in which i am using a sql override query, this error is in sql override. This mapping is failing with an error,

> '[IBM][CLI DRIVER]CLIO113E SQLSTATE 22007:An invalid datetime format
>   was detected, that is an invalid string representation or value was
>   specified'.

```
> Database driver error:
```

Function name:Fetch
SQL STMNT:

```
select s.employee_record_id,s.employee_id,s.record_origin,
cnt.employee_contract_id,cnt.employee_contract_efctv_dt,cnt.employee_contract_term_dt,club.employee_club

from

employee_main_info s

inner join

(select 

employee_id,record_origin,employee_contract_term_dt,employee_contract_efctv_dt
from employee_perm

union
select 

employee_id,record_origin,employee_contract_term_dt,employee_contract_efctv_dt
from employee_temp
) cnt on s.employee_id=cnt.employee_id,

employee_club_data club

where

club.employee_id=s.employee_id

and (cnt.employee_contract_efctv_dt <=sysdate or cnt.employee_contract_efctv_dt<'2016-01-01') 
and s.employee_record_term_dt>sysdate;
```

native error code= -99999

I have tried everything, my previous mappings have run fine with the same datetime formats but this one is failing. One thing i have noticed is that if i remove all the transformations in between the source qualifier and target the mapping succeeds and data gets loaded to target, but as soon as i put any lookups or expressions between source qualifier and target except a pass through expression, the mapping fails again.

Any suggestion, any help regarding this is appreciated.

Comment: You will have to upload more information then this. What sql exactly throws this error? in which transformation? the SQ? the LKP? and ETC

Comment: @Sagi, this error is in SQL override, the fetch fails. Database is DB2

Comment: Yes, I understand, but SQL override where? in what transformation

Comment: My initial guess is that `employee_temp.employee_contract_efctv_dt` is string-based, and contains an invalid value, which is then throwing during the `UNION` when it attempts to coerce the type to what is more probably an actual date type in the `employee_perm` table.

Comment: @ Sagi, In source qualifier transformation. When i dont add any transformation between the source qualifier and target (flat file) the query doesnt give errors, as soon as i add any expression transformation or lookup the error returns.

Answer (score 0):

We've seen this error occurring when SELECTing from a table with a timestamp column via the IBM Data Server ODBC/CLI driver. It only happened on one Windows machine and we were able to make the error disappear by changing the regional setting main selection from Israel to USA.

While not tested yet, it may be that the IBM DB2 ODBC configuration option DateTimeStringFormat or the attributes SQL_ATTR_DATE_FMT and SQL_ATTR_TIME_FMT can be used to force a specific format (such as JIS). See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0011525.html